# Java - convert named html entities to numbered xml entities

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, entities

I'm looking to convert an html block that contains html named entities to an xml compliant block that uses numbered xml entities while leaving all html tag elements in place.

This is the basic idea illustrated via test:

```
@Test
public void testEvalHtmlEntitiesToXmlEntities() {
    String input = "<a href=\"test.html\">link&nbsp;</a>";
    String expected = "<a href=\"test.html\">link&#160;</a>";
    String actual = SomeUtil.eval(input);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Is anyone aware of a Class that provides this functionality? I can write a regex to iterate through non element matches and do:

```
xlmString += StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(htmlString));
```

but hoped there is an easier way or a Class that already provides this.

Comment: This isn't far off: http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/src/org/freeshell/zs/common/HtmlManipulator.java.html, you just need to build a different map (with element[i] and element[i+1] in the static initialiser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)?

```
private String cleanData(String data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
    tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
    tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true); // only print the content
    tidy.setXmlOut(true); // to XML
    tidy.setSmartIndent(true); 
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Although I think it will repair some of your HTML code in case has something.

Comment: I have used JTidy on a previous project and it definitely could work. I am a bit concerned that it might manipulate <script /> content and other elements of the document in an unexpected way but i'll evaluate it and see. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I see the method `setNumEntities` in Tidy. Good luck!

Comment: This totally works so thank you. I wound up using a different method since I need to do this at render time in this particular use-case but this is a much better solution for most situations.

Comment: I received a string previously passed by `encodeURIComponent` for to be sent by `POST`. After the decoding, the string passed through `Tidy`, and finally turned into a `Java` object reading the `XML`.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I wound up using. Seems to work fine:

```
/**
 * Some helper methods for XHTML => HTML manipulation
 * 
 * @author David Maple<d@davemaple.com>
 *
 */
public class XhtmlUtil {

    private static final Pattern ENTITY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(&[^\\s]+?;)");

    /**
     * Don't instantiate me
     */
    private XhtmlUtil() { } 

    /**
     * Convert a String of HTML with named HTML entities to the 
     * same String with entities converted to numbered XML entities 
     * 
     * @param html
     * @return xhtml
     */
    public static String htmlToXmlEntities(String html) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher matcher = ENTITY_PATTERN.matcher(html);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = htmlEntityToXmlEntity(matcher.group(1));
            matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, "");
            stringBuffer.append(replacement);
        }

        matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Replace an HTML entity with an XML entity
     * 
     * @param htmlEntity
     * @return xmlEntity
     */
    private static String htmlEntityToXmlEntity(String html) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(html));
    }

}
```

and the corresponding tests:

```
public class XhtmlUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testEvalXmlEscape() {
        String input = "link 1 &nbsp;|&nbsp; link2 &amp; & dkdk;";
        String expected = "link 1 &#160;|&#160; link2 &amp; & dkdk;";
        String actual = XhtmlUtil.htmlToXmlEntities(input);
        System.out.println(actual);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEvalXmlEscape2() {
        String input = "<a href=\"test.html\">link&nbsp;</a>";
        String expected = "<a href=\"test.html\">link&#160;</a>";
        String actual = XhtmlUtil.htmlToXmlEntities(input);
        System.out.println(actual);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEvalXmlEscapeMultiLine() {
        String input = "<a href=\"test.html\">link&nbsp;</a>\n<a href=\"test.html\">link&nbsp;</a>";
        String expected = "<a href=\"test.html\">link&#160;</a>\n<a href=\"test.html\">link&#160;</a>";
        String actual = XhtmlUtil.htmlToXmlEntities(input);
        System.out.println(actual);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful to you.

```
private static Map<String, String> entityMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
static{
    entityMap.put("nbsp", "&#160;");
    entityMap.put("iexcl", "&#161;");
    entityMap.put("cent", "&#162;");
    entityMap.put("pound", "&#163;");
    entityMap.put("curren", "&#164;");
    entityMap.put("yen", "&#165;");
    entityMap.put("brvbar", "&#166;");
    entityMap.put("sect", "&#167;");
    entityMap.put("uml", "&#168;");
    entityMap.put("copy", "&#169;");
    entityMap.put("ordf", "&#170;");
    entityMap.put("laquo", "&#171;");
    entityMap.put("not", "&#172;");
    entityMap.put("shy", "&#173;");
    entityMap.put("reg", "&#174;");
    entityMap.put("macr", "&#175;");
    entityMap.put("deg", "&#176;");
    entityMap.put("plusmn", "&#177;");
    entityMap.put("sup2", "&#178;");
    entityMap.put("sup3", "&#179;");
    entityMap.put("acute", "&#180;");
    entityMap.put("micro", "&#181;");
    entityMap.put("para", "&#182;");
    entityMap.put("middot", "&#183;");
    entityMap.put("cedil", "&#184;");
    entityMap.put("sup1", "&#185;");
    entityMap.put("ordm", "&#186;");
    entityMap.put("raquo", "&#187;");
    entityMap.put("frac14", "&#188;");
    entityMap.put("frac12", "&#189;");
    entityMap.put("frac34", "&#190;");
    entityMap.put("iquest", "&#191;");
    entityMap.put("Agrave", "&#192;");
    entityMap.put("Aacute", "&#193;");
    entityMap.put("Acirc", "&#194;");
    entityMap.put("Atilde", "&#195;");
    entityMap.put("Auml", "&#196;");
    entityMap.put("Aring", "&#197;");
    entityMap.put("AElig", "&#198;");
    entityMap.put("Ccedil", "&#199;");
    entityMap.put("Egrave", "&#200;");
    entityMap.put("Eacute", "&#201;");
    entityMap.put("Ecirc", "&#202;");
    entityMap.put("Euml", "&#203;");
    entityMap.put("Igrave", "&#204;");
    entityMap.put("Iacute", "&#205;");
    entityMap.put("Icirc", "&#206;");
    entityMap.put("Iuml", "&#207;");
    entityMap.put("ETH", "&#208;");
    entityMap.put("Ntilde", "&#209;");
    entityMap.put("Ograve", "&#210;");
    entityMap.put("Oacute", "&#211;");
    entityMap.put("Ocirc", "&#212;");
    entityMap.put("Otilde", "&#213;");
    entityMap.put("Ouml", "&#214;");
    entityMap.put("times", "&#215;");
    entityMap.put("Oslash", "&#216;");
    entityMap.put("Ugrave", "&#217;");
    entityMap.put("Uacute", "&#218;");
    entityMap.put("Ucirc", "&#219;");
    entityMap.put("Uuml", "&#220;");
    entityMap.put("Yacute", "&#221;");
    entityMap.put("THORN", "&#222;");
    entityMap.put("szlig", "&#223;");
    entityMap.put("agrave", "&#224;");
    entityMap.put("aacute", "&#225;");
    entityMap.put("acirc", "&#226;");
    entityMap.put("atilde", "&#227;");
    entityMap.put("auml", "&#228;");
    entityMap.put("aring", "&#229;");
    entityMap.put("aelig", "&#230;");
    entityMap.put("ccedil", "&#231;");
    entityMap.put("egrave", "&#232;");
    entityMap.put("eacute", "&#233;");
    entityMap.put("ecirc", "&#234;");
    entityMap.put("euml", "&#235;");
    entityMap.put("igrave", "&#236;");
    entityMap.put("iacute", "&#237;");
    entityMap.put("icirc", "&#238;");
    entityMap.put("iuml", "&#239;");
    entityMap.put("eth", "&#240;");
    entityMap.put("ntilde", "&#241;");
    entityMap.put("ograve", "&#242;");
    entityMap.put("oacute", "&#243;");
    entityMap.put("ocirc", "&#244;");
    entityMap.put("otilde", "&#245;");
    entityMap.put("ouml", "&#246;");
    entityMap.put("divide", "&#247;");
    entityMap.put("oslash", "&#248;");
    entityMap.put("ugrave", "&#249;");
    entityMap.put("uacute", "&#250;");
    entityMap.put("ucirc", "&#251;");
    entityMap.put("uuml", "&#252;");
    entityMap.put("yacute", "&#253;");
    entityMap.put("thorn", "&#254;");
    entityMap.put("yuml", "&#255;");
    entityMap.put("fnof", "&#192;");
    entityMap.put("Alpha", "&#913;");
    entityMap.put("Beta", "&#914;");
    entityMap.put("Gamma", "&#915;");
    entityMap.put("Delta", "&#916;");
    entityMap.put("Epsilon", "&#917;");
    entityMap.put("Zeta", "&#918;");
    entityMap.put("Eta", "&#919;");
    entityMap.put("Theta", "&#920;");
    entityMap.put("Iota", "&#921;");
    entityMap.put("Kappa", "&#922;");
    entityMap.put("Lambda", "&#923;");
    entityMap.put("Mu", "&#924;");
    entityMap.put("Nu", "&#925;");
    entityMap.put("Xi", "&#926;");
    entityMap.put("Omicron", "&#927;");
    entityMap.put("Pi", "&#928;");
    entityMap.put("Rho", "&#929;");
    entityMap.put("Sigma", "&#931;");
    entityMap.put("Tau", "&#932;");
    entityMap.put("Upsi", "&#933;");
    entityMap.put("Phi", "&#934;");
    entityMap.put("Chi", "&#935;");
    entityMap.put("Psi", "&#936;");
    entityMap.put("Omega", "&#937;");
    entityMap.put("alpha", "&#945;");
    entityMap.put("beta", "&#946;");
    entityMap.put("gamma", "&#947;");
    entityMap.put("delta", "&#948;");
    entityMap.put("epsi", "&#949;");
    entityMap.put("zeta", "&#950;");
    entityMap.put("eta", "&#951;");
    entityMap.put("theta", "&#952;");
    entityMap.put("iota", "&#953;");
    entityMap.put("kappa", "&#954;");
    entityMap.put("lambda", "&#955;");
    entityMap.put("mu", "&#956;");
    entityMap.put("nu", "&#957;");
    entityMap.put("xi", "&#958;");
    entityMap.put("omicron", "&#959;");
    entityMap.put("pi", "&#960;");
    entityMap.put("rho", "&#961;");
    entityMap.put("sigmaf", "&#962;");
    entityMap.put("sigma", "&#963;");
    entityMap.put("tau", "&#964;");
    entityMap.put("upsi", "&#965;");
    entityMap.put("phi", "&#966;");
    entityMap.put("chi", "&#967;");
    entityMap.put("psi", "&#968;");
    entityMap.put("omega", "&#969;");
    entityMap.put("theta", "&#977;");
    entityMap.put("upsih", "&#978;");
    entityMap.put("piv", "&#982;");
    entityMap.put("bull", "&#8226;");
    entityMap.put("hellip", "&#8230;");
    entityMap.put("prime", "&#8242;");
    entityMap.put("Prime", "&#8243;");
    entityMap.put("oline", "&#8254;");
    entityMap.put("frasl", "&#8260;");
    entityMap.put("weierp", "&#8472;");
    entityMap.put("image", "&#8465;");
    entityMap.put("real", "&#8476;");
    entityMap.put("trade", "&#8482;");
    entityMap.put("alefsym", "&#8501;");
    entityMap.put("larr", "&#8592;");
    entityMap.put("uarr", "&#8593;");
    entityMap.put("rarr", "&#8594;");
    entityMap.put("darr", "&#8595;");
    entityMap.put("harr", "&#8596;");
    entityMap.put("crarr", "&#8629;");
    entityMap.put("lArr", "&#8656;");
    entityMap.put("uArr", "&#8657;");
    entityMap.put("rArr", "&#8658;");
    entityMap.put("dArr", "&#8659;");
    entityMap.put("hArr", "&#8660;");
    entityMap.put("forall", "&#8704;");
    entityMap.put("part", "&#8706;");
    entityMap.put("exist", "&#8707;");
    entityMap.put("empty", "&#8709;");
    entityMap.put("nabla", "&#8711;");
    entityMap.put("isin", "&#8712;");
    entityMap.put("notin", "&#8713;");
    entityMap.put("ni", "&#8715;");
    entityMap.put("prod", "&#8719;");
    entityMap.put("sum", "&#8722;");
    entityMap.put("minus", "&#8722;");
    entityMap.put("lowast", "&#8727;");
    entityMap.put("radic", "&#8730;");
    entityMap.put("prop", "&#8733;");
    entityMap.put("infin", "&#8734;");
    entityMap.put("ang", "&#8736;");
    entityMap.put("and", "&#8869;");
    entityMap.put("or", "&#8870;");
    entityMap.put("cap", "&#8745;");
    entityMap.put("cup", "&#8746;");
    entityMap.put("int", "&#8747;");
    entityMap.put("there4", "&#8756;");
    entityMap.put("sim", "&#8764;");
    entityMap.put("cong", "&#8773;");
    entityMap.put("asymp", "&#8773;");
    entityMap.put("ne", "&#8800;");
    entityMap.put("equiv", "&#8801;");
    entityMap.put("le", "&#8804;");
    entityMap.put("ge", "&#8805;");
    entityMap.put("sub", "&#8834;");
    entityMap.put("sup", "&#8835;");

    entityMap.put("nsub", "&#8836;");
    entityMap.put("sube", "&#8838;");
    entityMap.put("supe", "&#8839;");
    entityMap.put("oplus", "&#8853;");
    entityMap.put("otimes", "&#8855;");
    entityMap.put("perp", "&#8869;");
    entityMap.put("sdot", "&#8901;");

    entityMap.put("lceil", "&#8968;");
    entityMap.put("rceil", "&#8969;");
    entityMap.put("lfloor", "&#8970;");
    entityMap.put("rfloor", "&#8971;");
    entityMap.put("lang", "&#9001;");


    entityMap.put("loz", "&#9674;");

    entityMap.put("spades", "&#9824;");
    entityMap.put("clubs", "&#9827;");
    entityMap.put("hearts", "&#9829;");
    entityMap.put("diams", "&#9830;");


    entityMap.put("quot", "&#34;");
    entityMap.put("amp", "&#38;");
    entityMap.put("lt", "&#60;");
    entityMap.put("gt", "&#62;");

    entityMap.put("OElig", "&#338;");
    entityMap.put("oelig", "&#339;");
    entityMap.put("Scaron", "&#352;");
    entityMap.put("scaron", "&#353;");
    entityMap.put("Yuml", "&#376;");

    entityMap.put("circ", "&#710;");
    entityMap.put("tilde", "&#732;");

    entityMap.put("ensp", "&#8194;");
    entityMap.put("emsp", "&#8195;");
    entityMap.put("thinsp", "&#8201;");
    entityMap.put("zwnj", "&#8204;");
    entityMap.put("zwj", "&#8205;");
    entityMap.put("lrm", "&#8206;");
    entityMap.put("rlm", "&#8207;");
    entityMap.put("ndash", "&#8211;");
    entityMap.put("mdash", "&#8212;");
    entityMap.put("lsquo", "&#8216;");
    entityMap.put("rsquo", "&#8217;");
    entityMap.put("sbquo", "&#8218;");
    entityMap.put("ldquo", "&#8220;");
    entityMap.put("rdquo", "&#8221;");
    entityMap.put("bdquo", "&#8222;");
    entityMap.put("dagger", "&#8224;");
    entityMap.put("Dagger", "&#8225;");
    entityMap.put("permil", "&#8240;");
    entityMap.put("lsaquo", "&#8249;");
    entityMap.put("rsaquo", "&#8250;");
}
```

Then I simply append the data to the document as the DOCTYPE

```
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> " + " <!DOCTYPE some_name [ ");
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = entityMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
            buffer.append("<!ENTITY " + entry.getKey() + " \"" + entry.getValue() + "\">");
        }
        buffer.append(" ]>");

        convertedData = buffer.toString() + convertedData;
```

Comment: That would work for sure but it's a lot of data to transmit to the client on every request. This is for a mobile web app so I'd prefer to just render the entities appropriately. I definitely appreciate the input though.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have commons-lang on your classpath, look into the arrays in `EntityArrays`; they contain the mapping for all the entities.

To get the numeric value, just use `codePointAt(0)` on the first element (the Unicode character).

Now you need a regex-based loop to search for `&[^;]+;`. This is pretty safe since `&` is a special character which needs to be escaped. If you need to be 100% sure, look for CDATA elements and ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that I use

```
 /**
     * Converts the specified string which is in ASCII format to legal XML
     * format. Inspired by XMLWriter by http://www.megginson.com/Software/
     */
    public static String convertAsciiToXml(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.equals(""))
            return "";

        StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
        char ch[] = string.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            switch (ch[i]) {
                case '&':
                    sbuf.append("&amp;");
                    break;
                case '<':
                    sbuf.append("&lt;");
                    break;
                case '>':
                    sbuf.append("&gt;");
                    break;
                case '\"':
                    sbuf.append("&quot;");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (ch[i] > '\u007f') {
                        sbuf.append("&#");
                        sbuf.append(Integer.toString(ch[i]));
                        sbuf.append(';');
                    }
                    else if (ch[i] == '\t') {
                        sbuf.append(' ');
                        sbuf.append(' ');
                        sbuf.append(' ');
                        sbuf.append(' ');
                    }
                    else if ((int) ch[i] >= 32 || (ch[i] == '\n' || ch[i] == '\r')) {
                        sbuf.append(ch[i]);
                    }
            }
        }
        return sbuf.toString();
    }
```