# XMLParser encoding problems

Tags: android, xml, utf-8

```
public XMLParser(InputStream is) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db;
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        node = doc.getDocumentElement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        DebugLog.log(e);
    }
}
```

The inputStream contains content like: "Hey there this is a &uuml; character."
The character '&uuml;' is a 'ü';

When reading the node's content System.out.println(node.getTextContent()) I receive "hey there this is a character." &uuml; is cut of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is this a valid document? Does it have encoding specified?-> http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_encoding.asp

Those might help:

> [Howto let the SAX parser determine the encoding from the xml declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482494/howto-let-the-sax-parser-determine-the-encoding-from-the-xml-declaration)
>   http://www.coderanch.com/t/127052/XML/XML-parsers-encoding-byte-order

Comment: It's a HTML Webpage. ISO-8859-1

Comment: What is the default charset on device/machine?

Comment: Ach, just noticed tag. **IIRC** if not specified, the reader/parser assumes device( UTF-8 in this case ) encoding. You need to specify encoding( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) or create some custom InputStream which peeks encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the XML Entities and HTML Entities. 
I request a webpage which returns data with HTML Entities. 
I had to convert the HTML Entities to XML Entities and it worked!

[Check this answer for some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438694/java-convert-named-html-entities-to-numbered-xml-entities)