# XMLPullParser parser failed to parse "(??????) [????] &middot;" inside xml tag

Tags: java, exception, xml-parsing

I am parsing following XMLPullParser with Jsoup

```
<title>(??????) [????]0 BLACK LAGOON -???? &middot; ????- ?01-09?</title>
        <guid isPermaLink='true'>http://fenopy.eu/torrent/+black+lagoon+A+01+09+/OTcyOTA3Mw</guid>
        <pubDate>Wed, 27 Feb 2013 11:00:04 GMT</pubDate>
        <category>Anime</category>
        <link>http://fenopy.eu/torrent/+black+lagoon+A+01+09+/OTcyOTA3Mw</link>
        <enclosure url="http://fenopy.eu/torrent/-BLACK-LAGOON-01-09-/OTcyOTA3Mw==/download.torrent" length="569296173" type="application/x-bittorrent" />
        <description><![CDATA[ Category: Anime<br/>Size: 542.9 MB<br/>Ratio: 0 seeds, 3 leechers<br/> ]]></description>
        </item>
```

Here is my parsing code

```
int eventType = -1;

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch (eventType) {
                // at start of document: START_DOCUMENT
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:                      
                    break;

                // at start of a tag: START_TAG
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    // get tag name
                    String tagName = parser.getName();


                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_TITLE))                            
                        String t = parser.nextText();
```

When I call next text and it throws following exception..

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unresolved: &middot; (position:TEXT (??????) [????] ...@36:59 in java.io.StringReader@40540698) 
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error(KXmlParser.java:269)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushEntity(KXmlParser.java:818)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText(KXmlParser.java:849)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:354)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1378)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(KXmlParser.java:1432)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml isn't valid. `&middot;` is invalid reference for xml.

There are 5 predefined entity references in XML:

`&lt;`  <   less than

`&gt;`  >   greater than

`&amp;` &   ampersand

`&apos;`    '   apostrophe

`&quot;`    "   quotation mark

**Updated**

Simple use regex to replace all HTML characters from XML

```
XMLString.replaceAll("(&[^\\s]+?;)", ""));
```

this will replace `&middot;` by ""

Comment: Yeah but there are so many invalid invalid characters for xml. So is there any thing that it should do automatically... like setting some feature XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL do you know anything ?

Comment: I'm afraid, this references are out of xml specification, and they come from html spec. As I can see you have file that mix xml and html. There is method defineEntityReplacementText that can define replacement for entity reference, but you should define each reference you have. There is list of html entities http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Would you write a regex for me that remove everything all words that starts with & and ends with ;?

Comment: There was similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438694/java-convert-named-html-entities-to-numbered-xml-entities , may be you can use that solution?

Comment: Or you can use apache commons lang library. Method StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 convert entity reference to unicode character, but you should take care about encoding.

Answer (score 7):

I was dealing with the same problem and I found super easy solution:

```
xmlPullParser.setFeature(Xml.FEATURE_RELAXED, true);
```

Comment: To be clear: import android.util.Xml; ... XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser(); parser.setFeature(Xml.FEATURE_RELAXED, true);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do:

```
parser.setInput(...);
parser.defineEntityReplacementText("middot", "•");
```

---

***As this does not work with your implementation:***

From apache commons-lang use the HTML conversion, as it seems to be HTML named entities:

```
String xml = "<foo>Hello &middot; World!</foo>";
xml = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(xml);
```

---

***Comment's question:***

Replacing all indiscriminate:

```
String xml = "<...";

// Place all entities like "&middot;" in square brackets: "[middot]":
xml = xml.replaceAll("\\&(\\w+);", "[$1]");

// But not for the xml entities:
xml = xml.replaceAll("\\[(lt|gt|amp|quot|apos)\\]", "&$1;");
```

Comment: I did this after setting the input but this has no effect. do you know anything about setting XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL so that It should not throw exception on such elements...

Comment: Sorry no. You are thinking of first prefixing `<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE title [ <!ENTITY middot '.'> ]>...` ? Maybe before setInput (not so with my implementation)?

Comment: I want to remove all invalid characters from XML. Is there any regex or any library available to do so .. because I want to remove all of them.