# Android res/xml cannot escape apostrophe in any way

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-xmlpullparser

I have some XML files in `res/xml` and I'm trying to escape characters as you would normally do in XML. I tried nearly every way possible:

```
<tag>Okay, I'll do it</tag>
<tag>Okay, I\'ll do it</tag>
<tag>Okay, I&apos;ll do it</tag>
<tag>Okay, I&#x27;ll do it</tag>
<tag>Okay, I&#39;ll do it</tag>
```

None of them work, when I parse the file with `XmlPullParser`, I always get only part of the text: `Okay I`, split where the apostrophe was.

I also tried `parser.setFeature(Xml.FEATURE_RELAXED, true)`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822654/5288316), without success.

Is there any reason to this or any to fix this behavior?

EDIT: After more testing, it looks like this issue only happens with the apostrophe and no other escaped characters like `&amp;`.

Comment: I posted an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77840241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted [an issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77840241) about this and I was told this was intended behavior and would not be fixed. That really makes no sense but what can I do.

I was proposed using the `res/raw` folder, but then XML won't be optimized so I just used backtick `` ` `` and replaced it in code with an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this link and use the codes for your special characters.](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

For example: &#39 and add a semi-colon after 9 for '. I didn't add because it gets converted in to '.

Comment: No that doesn't work but I had actually made a mistake and wrote `&#89;` and I realized that it worked. It seems to only fail when the character is an apostrophe, but it works for `&amp;`. Very weird.